# Custom font for specific language shopify

Tags: css-selectors, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to add custom font anyway (url,name) for specific language my shopify store have two language , first language is english , secondary is arabic

I tried to do it using css in theme custom css but i can't mention arabic language selector like `shop-locale-ar {  font: font-name; }`
then i tried to do it using liquid  `{% if request.locale.iso_code == 'ar' %} here what i don't know how to select the font {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to give your body tag a class with the language .eng and .arabic, or just target arabic, have both fonts loaded in your store and just then just call the new font on body.arabic in css.

If you give the functionality to move between languages you need to write some javascript that will change this class on the selection of a new language.

The drawback to this is that you are loading both fonts all the time which is not optimal for performance but this is the easiest method.